# Remove a tab at runtime via containing form's button

Tags: delphi, lazarus

I'm creating tabs at run-time like this:

```
procedure TForm1.ShowFormOnTab(pProcName:String);
var
  Newform: TForm;
  ClassToUse: TFormClass;

  NewTab: TTabSheet;
  FormName: String;

begin
  NewTab := TTabSheet.Create(PageControl1);
  NewTab.PageControl:= PageControl1;

  PageControl1.ActivePage :=  NewTab;

  if pProcName='ProcfrmSetupItemCategories' then
    ClassToUse := TfrmSetupItemCategories
  else if pProcName='ProcfrmZones' then
    ClassToUse := TfrmZones
  else
    ClassToUse := nil;
  if Assigned(ClassToUse) then
    begin
      NewForm := ClassTouse.Create(NewTab);
      NewTab.Caption := NewForm.Caption;
    end;
```

Now, the tabs show correctly, and the forms appear on them as well. I need to do it this way since the forms + tabs are created at run-time.

But here's my question:
There's a close button on the form, which frees the form's resources when clicked. But I also want the TAB to get closed when the form's button is clicked.

How do I get around this?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to make it clear in the question, that you are using Lazrus and not Delphi. And which platforms you are targeting.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan It appears that both Lazarus and Delphi work the same in this area. But I'm only restricting the use of Windows APIs. So it must work on both Lazarus and Delphi (although Delphi itself is Windows only)

Comment: Please make it clear in the question body that you use Lazarus and list the platforms you target.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yeah, I think I should have been more specific. Thanks anyway for your method - it's certainly useful if I'm confining my app to Windows.

Comment: As an aside, it's quite funny running Lazarus and seeing one of the same bugs in menu rendering that I QC'ed for the Delphi IDE.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan And what might that bug be?

Comment: http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=86876

Comment: @DavidHeffernan And this is why I avoid the menu system as far as possible on Lazarus ;)

Comment: It's really easy to write Windows menus. The mistake that both Delphi and Lazarus IDE made was to use owner drawn menus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't like things getting to complicated

### How to get tabbed forms (PageControl)

```
TForm1 = class( TForm )
  PageControl1 : TPageControl;

  procedure NewTabbedForm;
end;

procedure TForm1.NewTabbedForm;
var
  LForm : TForm;
begin
  // Some code to get a new form instance into LForm

  LForm := TTabForm.Create( Self );

  // now the magic to put this form into PageControl as a TabSheet
  LForm.ManualDock( PageControl1, PageControl1, alClient );
  // Finally
  LForm.Show;
end;
```

The Caption of the form will be automatically used for the automatically created TabSheet Caption.

### How to free/remove a tabbed form

#### short and simple

```
TTabForm = class( TForm )
  Close_Button : TButton;
  procedure Close_ButtonClick( Sender : TObject );
end;

procedure TTabForm.Close_ButtonClick( Sender : TObject );
begin
  Self.Release;
end;
```

#### a little bit more

```
TTabForm = class( TForm )
  Close_Button : TButton;
  procedure Close_ButtonClick( Sender : TObject );
  procedure FormClose( Sender : TObject; var Action : TCloseAction );
end;

procedure TTabForm.Close_ButtonClick( Sender : TObject );
begin
  Self.Close;
end;

procedure TTabForm.FormClose( Sender : TObject; var Action : TCloseAction );
begin
  Action := caFree;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for this superb concept. Really appreciate the time you've taken to do this.

Comment: SirRufo, Why do you use Self here? it is obsolete here :)

Comment: Isn't this Delphi rather than Lazarus?

Comment: @whosrdaddy i use Self to point out that Release and Close are methods from the form class and nothing special ;o)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I didn't test with fpc/lazarus but all methods are basics and exists

Comment: @DavidHeffernan ManualDock is needed for DragDrop behavior inherited from TControl. Do you think they missed this basic functionality in lazarus? And i have checked lcl docs before my answer http://wiki.freepascal.org/LCL_Drag_Dock

Comment: I didn't think anything. Which is why I asked.

Comment: @SirRufo Does this method of working with manualdock rely on the Windows API?

Comment: @itsols i didn't find anything in the docs that this is limited to windows - and i would not expect

Answer (score 4):

You can simply `Free` the tab sheet. You don't need to separately free the children of the tab sheet. Just call `Free` on the tab sheet and you are done.

However, if the button lives on the tab sheet that is being freed, that will not work. It is not possible to free the parent of the button from the button's `OnClick` event handler.

The solution is to post your self a message. The message needs to contain the information needed to free the tab sheet. By posting the message you allow the `OnClick` event handler to run to completion before the queued message is processed.

```
const
  WM_FREECONTROL = WM_USER;
....
PostMessage(Self.Handle, WM_FREECONTROL, 0, LParam(TabSheet));
```

Then add a handler for the message to the form:

```
procedure WMFreeControl(var Message: TMessage); message WM_FREECONTROL;
```

and implement it like this:

```
procedure TForm1.WMFreeControl(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  TObject(Message.LParam).Free;
end;
```

Now, having written this lengthy response, do be clear that the advice from paragraph 2 onwards only applies in the case where the button is a child of the control that is being freed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this info. Looking at the lines of code, they seem workable but I believe this will restrict me to MS-Windows. Why I say that is because I presume this is using the Windows API. While I'm sure this is a straight forward technique, I'd like to know if you have an alternative that doesn't use the API. Forgive me for my ignorance. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is your close button inside the tab sheet that is being freed?

Comment: @david-hefferman Yes, the close button is on the form and the form is on the tab sheet. I know this is a problem like you've correctly stated :(

Comment: OK. So I guess we need to find a similar approach, but without PostMessage.